# Laravel mix hot reload and domain name

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix

I use Laravel Homestead for my development environment, so my website is accessible on http://test.app

Now I tried to configure laravel mix to use it with VUEJS. For this, I include a JS file in one of my templates:

```
<script src="{{ url(mix('js/main.js'))}}"></script>
```

The result of this is

```
<script src="//localhost:8080/js/main.js"></script>
```

It seems so, that the localhost:8080 is hardcoded in vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helper.php (see https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/e35a60f7f3ef1d75754522771f13762b3058f1b0/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php#L560)

How to fix this or how I done something wrong?

Comment: what version of laravel-mix, laravel are you using?

Comment: I believe you don't need the `url()` function you can just use `mix('js/main.js')` this function will provide you a relative path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the source you quote will only be executed in watch mode.

In this case, Laravel mix host a server on 8080 port for all your static files (css, js) so you can get the hot-reload feature, while the php files still running on your Homestead Niginx, and I don't see anything wrong with it.

it will compile to your APP_URL in production mode and if 8080 is somehow conflicting with your other service you can modify config file of Laravel Mix.

Comment: cwang is correct, the the HMR will use your homestead url as a proxy if you have set it up as it states here https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mix#browsersync-reloading. So there should there shouldn't be any issue with this in production

Answer (score 0):

try setting APP_URL in your .env config file

```
APP_URL = http://test.app
```

i hope it helps.

Comment: I have done this of course. But that will not help, because its hardcoded: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/e35a60f7f3ef1d75754522771f13762b3058f1b0/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php#L560