# How can I run Laravel mix on custom URL?

Tags: node.js, laravel, vue.js, npm, laravel-mix

I am creating one application that needs to be made on staging server from one point. Because creating it on local is impossible as it has some endpoints that other servers in network has to access.

I have created an application in Vue.js and Laravel. In local, I used to run `npm run hot` so that I don't have to re-compile when I change some code. But as I have to continue developing this application on a live server, I want to run `npm run hot` on a custom domain like `staging.something.com` instead of `localhost:8080`.

I don't have any issue if somehow `localhost:8080` co-operates but when I run `npm run hot` on a live server, Here is the error I get when I try to access the web application.

```
GET http://localhost:8080//js/app.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I think it should show IP address of my server instead of `localhost`. I don't know what's wrong with this but it's not working.

Comment: You can't use `localhost` to refer to a non-local host. How are you generating that url to begin with?

Comment: I know that. I am not generating that URL. Laravel mix or webpack is generating that URL. I want my custom domain instead of localhost:8080!

Comment: [Rumour has it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47127503/laravel-mix-hot-reload-and-domain-name) that this is controlled by your `APP_URL` entry in `.env`

Comment: I already have "APP_URL" set in my `.env` file. It works when you deploy your application in production. But I want to execute it for development. So that I don't have to re-compile every time I make some changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Laravel mix uses the webpack-dev-server package for the `run hot` command.

webpack-dev-server has a switch `--useLocalIp` which will make it use the servers local IP address.

It also has a `--host` switch which can be used to set the IP address manually `--host 0.0.0.0`